# Javascript variable value lost

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I need help.

I have two grids:

```
<table id="section"></table>
<div id="pager_sec"></div>
<table id="details"></table>
<div id="pager_det"></div>
```

And this variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var section_id;
```

SET the variable with the row selected on section. alert show the right value:

```
jQuery("#section").jqGrid({

    onSelectRow: function (id) {

            section_id = id;
            alert(section_id);
    }

});
```

But in editData of navgrid add operation the variable has not value:

```
jQuery("#details").jqGrid({

});

jQuery("#details").navGrid('#pager_det',{add:true},{editData:{num_section: section_id});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Umm... `section_id` ≠ `id_section`

Comment: Yes, I did not want to copy the complete code. In the real code is ok the variable name.

Comment: Alright... Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You should use callback functions inside of `editData` instead of properties:

```js
editData: {
    num_section: function () { return section_id; }
}
```

If will force the usage of *the current* value of `section_id` variable. You current code uses the value of `section_id` variable at the moment of calling `navGrid` method.

Comment: Thanks Oleg for your help!

Comment: @Mariano: You are welcome! Do you tried the changes? Is your problem solved now?

Comment: I can't try until monday. I let you know.